# envelope rms implementation by Matlab

Tags: matlab, envelope

I am trying to implement the moving RMS by Matlab.

```
x = randn(50, 1);
xRMS = sqrt(movmean(x.^2, 21));
xRMSref = envelope(x, 21, 'rms');
plot(xRMSref,'DisplayName','xRMSref');hold on;plot(xRMS,'DisplayName','xRMS');hold off;
legend()
```

Why my estimation differs from Matlab's?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `envelope` centers the signal before computing the standard deviation and afterwards corrects for the mean. Try this instead:

```
x = randn(50, 1);
xRMS = sqrt(movmean(x.^2, 21));
xRMS_centered = sqrt(movmean((x-mean(x)).^2, 21)) + mean(x);
xRMSref = envelope(x, 21, 'rms');
plot(xRMSref,'x-','DisplayName','xRMSref');hold on;plot(xRMS,'o-','DisplayName','xRMS');plot(xRMS_centered,'s-','DisplayName','xRMS centered');hold off;
legend()
```

***edit**: since you were asking why envelope behaves this way: I think it's because it tries to return an *envelope* of the signal. It actually comes with two output arguments, a lower and an upper envelope with the idea that the signal should be between the two. Clearly if that's what we want, we need to account for the mean. See example in the following figure:

[image: Example for envelope function]

If you didn't center, you wouldn't capture the local variation around the mean accordingly.

Comment: any reason why they are doing it? Is their solution is better than mine?

Comment: also, is there any reference for such practice?

Comment: in RMS you don't remove the mean while when computing standard deviation you remove the mean...

Comment: @Ben but we are computing the rms rather than the std, right?

Comment: the RMS includes the DC part. However, you called the Matlab envelope function. The envelope excludes the DC part.

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan: I added some explanation and an example for why I think the centering is included in the `envelope` function.

Comment: @Florian  Thanks a lot. It clarified everything

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.