# Problem with starting values when recreating the matlab envelope function in python

Tags: matlab, python, envelope

I am trying to recreate the [envelope](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/envelope.html) function from matlab in python, but I have a problem with the initial values. I have a window of 1000 and the first 1000 values won't show up. Here is a snippet of my code with a picture from the result:

```
mean = np.mean(current_winners)
substract_current = [x - mean for x in current_winners]
power = [x**2 for x in substract_current]

power_series = pd.Series(power)
windows = power_series.rolling(1000)
moving_avg = windows.mean()
moving_avg_list = moving_avg.to_list()


sqrt_list = [math.sqrt(x) for x in moving_avg_list]

final = [x + np.mean(current_winners) for x in sqrt_list]

plt.plot(final)
plt.show()
```

[image: Result of python code]

And here is the code I use in matlab with the matlab result:

```
sam_nouv = envelope(current_average,1000,'rms');
plot(sam_nouv)
```

[image: Result of matlab code]

For my python code, I tried to replicate the code I saw in this post:
[envelope rms implementation by Matlab](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70502/envelope-rms-implementation-by-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the call to

```
windows = power_series.rolling(1000)
```

Per the
[documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html), try instead:

```
windows = power_series.rolling(1000, min_periods=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sadly it outputs this plot (https://imgur.com/a/EGXNRv9) which is not the same as the one in matlab

Comment: Seems to me they do match, expect the python version has a few extra values at the beginning (I'm guessing 500 extra values). You have to do *some* digging yourself Manuel!

Comment: I will try to see if I can find something about this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried putting the min_periods=500 and now the plots match, the problem is that now, the plot start at 500.

Comment: Can’t you just shift to the left by discarding the first 500 values? I’m assuming they’re all Nans. Or use min_periods=1 and discard the first 500 Values…

Comment: It's probably what I am gonna do, I just don't understand why the size is not the same with matlab and python

Comment: @Manuel did you figure this out?